# Beginner: Min Value in Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, min

when I execute this program, it prints the max value just fine, however the min value always prints to zero. I continue to scratching my head... Can anyone see what is wrong here? Thanks for looking.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class MinMax
    {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] numbers = new int[5];
        int max = numbers[0]; 
        int min = numbers[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your next number:");
            numbers[i] = kb.nextInt();
            if (numbers[i] > max)
            {
                max = numbers[i];
            }
            if (min > numbers[i])
            {
                min = numbers[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The maximum value in your array is " + max);
        System.out.println("The minimum value in your array is " + min);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when the array is declared, the ints in the array are set to 0. Setting the min to `numbers[0]` would set min to 0. If that's not your min, your code will fail.

In this case, you don't need the array - you could just store whatever the user inputted. That aside, just check whether `i==0` and when it does, set min and max to `numbers[0]`. (If you didn't do the same for max, an array of all negatives would fail.)

Comment: testing this with all negative numbers makes the max 0 and the min = to the actual min in the user input array!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. The min variable is never updated because every time that min > numbers[i] is evaluated returns false. Let's to see an example:

1. min = 0.0 > numbers[i] = 4.5 -> false
2. min = 0.0 > numbers[i] = 3.8 -> false
3. min = 0.0 > numbers[i] = -8.9 -> true, min = -8.9
4. min = -8.9 > numbers[i] = 7.5 -> false
5. min = -8.9 < numbers[i] = 5.6 -> false

The value of min is: **-8.9**

With Java 8 you can get the max and min values easy with lambdas:

```
max = Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsDouble();
min = Arrays.stream(numbers).min().getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers here are saying, the problem is that `numbers[0]` *starts out* initialized to `0`, so regardless of the numbers the user enters, your code still finds `0` to be the minimum value.

What you need is an extra state to represent "I don't have any minimum value yet". You could use an extra `boolean` variable to represent this tate, or if you can use the `Integer` wrapper type, you can use `null`.

For example:

```
Integer minimum = null;
Integer maximum = null;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  int number = kb.nextInt();
  if (minimum == null || number < minimum) {
    minimum = number;
  }
  if (maximum == null || number > maximum) {
    maximum = number;
  }
}

System.out.println("minimum: " + minimum);
System.out.println("maximum: " + maximum);
```